Manga in which the main character is reincarnated in a forest and given the powers of water magic and eternal youth
I'm looking for a manga in which the main character is reincarnated in a forest. He is given the power to use water magic and eternal youth.
I'm sure it has less than 50 chapters.

Is this The Water Magician...?

Upon being reincarnated into a fantasy world, Ryo wants to live out his days in peace with his newfound water magic. He can only conjure a cupful at a time, but it’s enough to eek out a comfortable existence—or so he thought. The powers that be cast him into the wild outlands with nothing more than a humble shack, a single knife, some food...and abilities that are yet beyond his comprehension. The area is overrun by monsters and there’s nary another human in sight. Ryo must now figure out how to survive above all else, but he’s ready to take bulls, boars, and a whole host of other monsters by the horns if it means seizing the life he wants for himself. Each new victory brings a new challenge, but what could a fateful encounter with a headless horseman, a dragon, and a castaway swordsman have in common? They’re the first steps on a grand journey that will take Ryo beyond the borders of all he knows to become the greatest water magician the world has ever seen—one adventure at a time.

The main character, Ryo Mihara, is hit by a truck and dies. He then finds himself in a white void with a wingless angel who tells him he's going to be reincarnated in another world with an aptitude for water magic.



He then wakes up in a house in a forest, and shortly after learns that he also has the hidden trait of eternal youth.



